# Linux distro with 2.4 kernel, that has GNOME

Tags: linux

I am looking for a Linux distro with 2.4 kernel, that can run Gnome.

Can't seem to find anything. Please provide links to iso files also.

Comment: 2.4?! What kind of distro are you looking for? (Don't say GNOME, it's in most distros)

Comment: @TomWijsman: Any debian based distro would be cool. I know Ubuntu does not have a 2.4 release. I have no bias otherwise as long as it has a GNOME environment

Comment: By '2.4' I think you mean kernel 2.4... why do you need it?

Comment: As in, Linux *kernel* version 2.4? CentOS 3.9 was the last version to contain a 2.4.x kernel. But *why* are you trying to do this?

Comment: Yes I mean kernel 2.4. I am trying to install MPLS Linux. I know I can install it on my current system by downgrading stuff but I am getting errors that I can't resolve.

Comment: @allquixotic: Why are there 3 isos? Which one should I install? http://mirror.hmc.edu/centos/3.9/isos/i386/

Comment: @Bruce they are 3 ISOs for 3 install CDs.

Comment: Why would you want mpls on a system with a GUI?

Comment: Please explain exactly what you want to do, and why. Running some experimental version of Linux in anger isn't for newbies...

Answer (score 7):

Stop trying to use ancient software right now.

[MPLS-Linux](https://github.com/i-maravic/MPLS-Linux) is a *current* (3.x) Linux kernel with MPLS support.

Comment: this version does not have firewall support which I need.

Answer (score 0):

*Every* major distribution shipped (still does) with Gnome. It's harder to find a mainstream distribution that does not include Gnome. If you need a suggestion, Slackware is like a time machine when it comes to finding old software.